# "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xad in position 2491: invalid start byte"

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, subprocess, pdftotext

In this code:

```
subprocess.getoutput('./pdftotext file.pdf -')
```

Also I tried `UTF-16`:

```
subprocess.check_output('./pdftotext file.pdf -', shell=True, encoding='utf-16')
```

The PDF from https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf, but I see the same error (with another byte value) for another PDF.

This PDF from Mozilla behaves well with pure Bash without Python.

Also I tried param `universal_newlines=True`, for example:

```
return subprocess.run(
      './pdftotext file.pdf -',
      shell=True,
      stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
      universal_newlines=True
).stdout
```

Python 3.6 on Lambda.

Comment: Hm, works for me (as UTF-8) with that PDF. Is there anything unusual about that `pdftotext`? Given that there’s a `./`…. Does it work for you locally?

Comment: @Ry- I tried also on EC2 with the same image as on Lambda, I tried on Ubuntu 18.04 in VirtualBox, and I tried on my local Mac - and everywhere with the same result as in my question, how it is possible? What is version of your Python? What version of your `pdftotext`? Operating system?

Comment: pdftotext 0.70.1 on Linux. Python 3.7.1, but that shouldn’t matter (I’m *assuming* it doesn’t behave well outside of Python, it’s just that nothing ensures it’s valid UTF-8.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Filter" output with [iconv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) - with ignoring of errors:

```
subprocess.getoutput('./pdftotext file.pdf - | iconv --to-code utf-8//IGNORE')
```

Feel free to add your answers - just curious about alternative solutions and the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try next code:

```
return subprocess.run(
      './pdftotext file.pdf -',
      shell=True,
      stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
      universal_newlines=True,
      encoding='your encoding',
      errors='ignore', # 'ignore' or 'replace'
).stdout
```

More about:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode
https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers